# issue with Windows Server 2012 in Gcp

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have one VM in Compute Engine with Windows Server 2012 R2 and I connected the server with my AD on-premise. The connection is with VPN network. but only have traffic from GCP to my Local network.

I can joint the server to my Domain but, every day the server show message " the specific domain either does not exist or could not be contacted".

i listen you Ideas... very thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be because of IPV6. Disabling it on the servers and workstations can solve the issue. Once disabled, run  ipconfig /flushdns and Ipconfig /registerDNS disabled NIC, enabled NIC and hopefully solved the issue.

Comment: thanks for the answer. now i have traffic in both senses from my network on-premise to GCP and vice versa. I Wiil follow you advice and give you  a feedback

Comment: hi man, thanks for the help. i think so that is resolved